# How to provision dashboards into kibana?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, saltstack, kibana

I am giving my developers the gift of kibana using the elasticsearch that is bundled with logstash. They will have kibana in their vagrant boxes.

Goal: Install and configure kibana dashboards via scripts on startup.

Problem: How to pre-load exported dashboards into elasticsearch embedded in logstash?

I have downloaded the dashboards, let's call the file: "fancy.json". Once logstash is up and running how can I automate loading fancy.json into elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you mean by `kibana using the elasticsearch embedded in logstash`? Kibana, Logstash and Elastic are all very different products and as far as I know don't come "bundled".

Comment: Elasticsearch is bundled into logstash. I like to give context with my questions. The issue is how to pre-load the previously exported dashboards at provision time.

Comment: Again, I don't think the two products come bundled together. There's an ES output for LS, is that what you mean?

Comment: Really, it has always been bundled.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-embedded

Comment: Well would you look at that! If you have your json file with the dashboard, why can't you just load it into the `.kibana` index with a shell script?

Comment: That is pretty much the question - with a twist for how to wait for es to come up, which I consider a separate issue.

Comment: The method will really depend on the platform. `ExecStartPost` would work Linux's using systemd, with an init-script for those that aren't, while a Windows service that depends on the LS service would work on Windows. Either way, the script would have to run `wget` or `curl` requests (using PowerShell on Windows) to check that ES is up before POSTing the dashboards.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example of how to post any dashboard via curl? I suppose I should create another question for that.

Comment: Elastic has posted just that for importing the Beats dashboards: https://github.com/elastic/beats-dashboards, in particular the `load.sh` script.

Comment: Huzzah!  `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/.kibana/dashboard/$dashbord_name
        -d @$exported_json_file`

Comment: Yeah, but you need to load all the elements that the dashboard depends on (Visualizations, Searches and Index Patterns).

Comment: Kibana 3 - until Kibana 4 works with firefox it is right out.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured this out.

Instead I now copy the exported dashboard into /opt/kibana/app/dashboards/company.json and set the default dashboard in /opt/kibana/config.js to point to it.